# Parse C Array Size with Python & LibClang

Tags: python, c, arrays, parsing, libclang

I am currently using Python to parse a C file using `LibClang`. I've encountered a problem while reading a C-array which size is defined by a define-directive-variable.

With node.get_children i can perfectly read the following array:

```
int myarray[20][30][10];
```

As soon as the array size is replaced with a variable, the array won't be read correctly. The following array code can't be read.

```
#define MAX 60;
int myarray[MAX][30][10];
```

Actually the parser stops at MAX and in the dump there is the error: invalid sloc.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the code through a C preprocessor before trying to parse it. That will cause all preprocessor-symbols to be replaced by their values, i.e. your `[MAX]` will become `[60]`.

Note that C code can also do this:

```
const int three[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

i.e. let the compiler deduce the length of the array from the number of initializer values given.

Or, from C99, even this:

```
const int hundred[] = { [99] = 4711 };
```

So a naive approach might still break, but I don't know anything about the capabilities of the parser you're using, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as matter of fact, the error is Much simpler than i thought. The semicolon in the define was causing the error. Anyways, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon ; in the define directive way causing the error.